# Docker Environment variables definition

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm running my Docker container like this:

```
nvidia-docker run --publish 0.0.0.0:8080:8888 -e LD_LIBRARY_PATH=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/tensorrt/lib -it container:latest bash
```

In my host `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is:

```
/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/nccl2/lib:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
```

I need to migrate to Dockerfile using ENV, how to change the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` into `ENV`, without hardcoding the value?

Will this use the Host value?

```
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/tensorrt/lib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of [--build-arg](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) option of `docker build` command.

Change your dockerfile to this

```
FROM same-base-image
ARG LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/tensorrt/lib
```

Build docker image with `--build-arg` option

```
docker build --build-arg LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH -t myimage:v1 .
```

**NOTE:** Here `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is pointing to environment variable on the host machine.

Now run the docker container and confirm the variable is properly set.

```
$ docker run -itd myimage:v1 sh
$ docker exec -it mycontainer env
```

Hope this helps.